# Office update killed my VBA code to paste Excel tables to an existing PowerPoint file and slides

Tags: vba, excel, powerpoint

After a recent Office 365 update, my code to copy tables from Excel to Power Point stopped working.

Previous code:

```
Sub GeneratePresentation()

Dim pptApp As PowerPoint.Application
Dim pptPrez As PowerPoint.Presentation
Dim pSlide As PowerPoint.Slide
Dim objPPT As Object
Dim myRange As Excel.Range

Set objPPT = CreateObject("PowerPoint.Application")
objPPT.Visible = True

MonthNo = Month(Worksheets("inputs").Range("B3"))
MonthData = Worksheets("inputs").Cells(MonthNo + 10, 9)

If MonthData = "" Then
    MsgBox "Please update losses"

Else

    FilePath = "\\Model\"
    Filename = "Template Monthly reports.pptx"
    file = FilePath & Filename
    Set pptPrez = objPPT.Presentations.Open(file)

    Set pptApp = GetObject(Class:="PowerPoint.Application")
    Set pptPrez = pptApp.ActivePresentation

'Slide 1 title 1
    Set pSlide = pptPrez.Slides(1)
    Sheets("01").Range("D3") = "= ""Midstream Monthly Production Report "" & Text(Inputs!B3, ""Mmmm YYYY"") & "" - internal"""
    Sheets("01").Range("D3").Copy
    Set osh = pSlide.Shapes.PasteSpecial(ppPasteDefault)(1)
    With osh
        .Top = 160
        .Left = 135
        .Height = 80
        .Width = 550
    End With
```

Code continues to paste tables and pictures. then

```
End if
End sub
```

I get the following error:

> VBA error Run-time '-2147188160 (80048240)': Shapes (unknown member)

I have tried most variants of paste but it only lets me paste pictures or text. I noticed that the VBA refernce library revision seems to have reduced to Microsoft PowerPoint 14.0 Object library when I am fairly sure it was build 15 or 16 before. Would this be the cause?

I have come up with a solution which is to use

```
'Slide 1 title 1
i = 1
Set pSlide = pptPrez.Slides(i)
Sheets("01").Range("D3") = "= ""Midstream Monthly Production Report "" & Text(Inputs!B3, ""Mmmm YYYY"") & "" - internal"""
Sheets("01").Range("D3").Copy
pptPrez.Windows(1).Activate
pptPrez.Windows(1).View.GotoSlide i
pptPrez.Slides(i).Shapes("Title").Select
pptApp.CommandBars.ExecuteMso ("PasteSourceFormatting")
With pptPrez.Slides(i)
    With .Shapes("Title")
        .LockAspectRatio = msoFalse
        .Top = 160
        .Left = 135
        .Height = 70
        .Width = 550
        '.TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Name = "Futura Bold"
        '.TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Size = 24
        '.TextFrame.TextRange.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = ppAlignLeft
        '.TextFrame.TextRange.ParagraphFormat.WordWrap = msoTrue
    End With
End With
```

For the alternative, I have to create all the tables manually then name them and select them in the code which works, but it seems less consistent and reliable requiring the windows to be active being more to go wrong.

Any ideas how to get the first code working again? I can paste manually still but it seems not using pastespecial. Why would an update remove this ability? I've tried proven code from this forum using this paste function but it won't work either which used to, It's definitely the update as all our computers now have the same issue which I find hard to believe too.

Comment: The code fails on PasteSpecial? PasteSpecial is a relative newcomer to PowerPoint VBA, but I thought it was around for Office 14 (2010). The reference to version 14.0 of the PowerPoint library is strange. Can you go to Tools > References and scroll to version 16.0? What version of Office are you using: go to File tab > Account, and find the version number and build number.

Comment: Why do you have both CreateObject and GetObject. For PowerPoint, you only need to do this once, using CreateObject. If PowerPoint is running, CreateObject returns the running instance; if not, it returns a new instance. Probably not important, but it adds clutter. Move CreateObject up to where GetObject is, and change objPPT to pptApp (since you don't need both).

Comment: Also, you've used three variables which are not declared. Declare MonthNo and MonthData as Variant and osh as PowerPoint.Shape (actually, in my code I renamed it pptShape and pSlide to pptSlide for consistency).

Comment: With the additional modification to use the active presentation instead of opening one at a given path and file name, your code works fine for me. I'm running Version 1711, Build 8711.2037, for what it's worth.

Answer (score 1):

I decided to write an answer instead of a bunch of comments, since I wanted to post my code.

Those Office 365 updates have caught me a time or three. But I don't know what's the problem.

The code fails on PasteSpecial? PasteSpecial is a relative newcomer to PowerPoint VBA, but I thought it was around for Office 14 (2010). The reference to version 14.0 of the PowerPoint library is strange. Can you go to Tools > References and scroll to version 16.0? If so, check that one instead. What version of Office are you using: go to File tab > Account, and find the version number and build number.

Why do you have both CreateObject and GetObject. For PowerPoint, you only need to do this once, using CreateObject. If PowerPoint is running, CreateObject returns the running instance; if not, it returns a new instance. Probably not important, but it adds clutter. Move CreateObject up to where GetObject is, and change objPPT to pptApp (since you don't need both).

Also, you've used three variables which are not declared. Declare MonthNo and MonthData as Variant and osh as PowerPoint.Shape (actually, in my code I renamed it pptShape and pSlide to pptSlide for consistency).

With the additional modification to use the active presentation instead of opening one at a given path and file name, your code works fine for me. I'm running Version 1711, Build 8711.2037, for what it's worth.

And here's the code that ran fine for me.

```
Sub GeneratePresentation()
  Dim pptApp As PowerPoint.Application
  Dim pptPrez As PowerPoint.Presentation
  Dim pptSlide As PowerPoint.Slide
  Dim myRange As Excel.Range
  Dim pptShape As PowerPoint.Shape
  Dim MonthNo As Variant
  Dim MonthData As Variant

  MonthNo = Month(Worksheets("inputs").Range("B3"))
  MonthData = Worksheets("inputs").Cells(MonthNo + 10, 9)

  If MonthData = "" Then
    MsgBox "Please update losses"

  Else
    Set pptApp = GetObject(Class:="PowerPoint.Application")
    Set pptPrez = pptApp.ActivePresentation

    '' JP - use active presentation instead of opening one
    ''FilePath = "\\Model\"
    ''Filename = "Template Monthly reports.pptx"
    ''file = FilePath & Filename
    ''Set pptPrez = objPPT.Presentations.Open(file)
    Set pptPrez = pptApp.ActivePresentation

    'Slide 1 title 1
    Set pptSlide = pptPrez.Slides(1)
    Sheets("01").Range("D3") = "= ""Midstream Monthly Production Report "" _
        & Text(Inputs!B3, ""Mmmm YYYY"") & "" - internal"""
    Sheets("01").Range("D3").Copy
    Set pptShape = pptSlide.Shapes.PasteSpecial(ppPasteDefault)(1)
    With pptShape
      .Top = 160
      .Left = 135
      .Height = 80
      .Width = 550
    End With
  End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Jon, When I ran your above code it still came up with the same error on the pppastedefault line. I have looked through the references for build 16 but it is not available only 14. The office version is 1705 (build 8201.2200). Jon

Comment: I have found that ppPateDefault does work for pictures but just no longer works for tables. Despite being able to right click in the presentation and pasting it keeping the format.

Comment: You could use CopyPicture instead of Copy on the Excel side (choose either Picture or Bitmap, after testing the quality and behavior of each), followed by plain old Paste on the PowerPoint side.

Comment: The wrong library numbers are bizarre; I wonder if the upgrade messed this up. Look for PowerPoint at `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Root\Office16\MSPPT.OLB`or wherever Office was installed. If it's there, go to Tools > References, and browse to add it.

Comment: I have two folders "office14" and "office16", it seems office14 is full of files and office16 only has 4 files. I thought initially it was a messed up installation, but it won't work on anyone's PC anymore in my organistion. I now have a full solution using the "CommandBars.ExecuteMso ("PasteSourceFormatting"). I am now working on a function CreateTable to simplify it (30 tables). Once completed I'll post my solution for anyone else who encounters this issue or wants to paste multiple tables from excel to existing PowerPoint slides using  "CommandBars.ExecuteMso ("PasteSourceFormatting").

Comment: Do you have a home computer you can try it on? The installation pushed out by your IT department at work might have problems. If it were your own computer, I would suggest a repair installation.

Comment: I noticed that my references have changed again to build 16 but it still doesn't work. I will see what my IT department come up with but won't hold my breath. I will try it at home, but I'm 99% sure it will work.

Answer (score 0):

I have updated the alternative solution which might help others as it does a few things; copies tables to an existing presentation and slides updating old shapes and new shapes, copies pictures to new slides with a pop up box to allow a choice in pasting a table.

I made a function to do this to reduce the main code and make it easier to manage as I had dozens of copies and pastes. I haven't pasted everything but showed some of the different ways to paste:

```
Public Declare PtrSafe Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32" (ByVal dwMilliseconds As LongPtr)
Private pptApp As PowerPoint.Application
Private pptPres As PowerPoint.Presentation
Private pSlide As PowerPoint.Slide
Private TTop, TLeft As Variant
Private TableCount, SlideNo As Integer
Private MyRange As Excel.Range
Private ShapeName As String
Private Function CreateTable()

Dim l As Long

Set pSlide = pptPres.Slides(SlideNo)
MyRange.Copy
pptPres.Windows(1).Activate
pptPres.Windows(1).View.GotoSlide SlideNo

With pptPres.Slides(SlideNo)
    If ShapeName = isblank Then
    Else
    pptPres.Slides(SlideNo).Shapes(ShapeName).Select
    End If
            For l = 1 To 100
        DoEvents
    Next l
    pptApp.CommandBars.ExecuteMso ("PasteSourceFormatting")
    For l = 1 To 500
        DoEvents
    Next l
    pptApp.CommandBars.ReleaseFocus
    NoShapes = pSlide.Shapes.Count
    If ShapeName = isblank Then
        pptPres.Slides(SlideNo).Shapes(NoShapes).Name = "Table" & TableCount
        pptPres.Slides(SlideNo).Shapes(ShapeName).Select
        With .Shapes("Table" & TableCount)
            .LockAspectRatio = msoFalse
            If TTop = isblank Then
            Else
                .Top = TTop
            End If
            If TLeft = isblank Then
            Else
                .Left = TLeft
            End If
        End With
    TableCount = TableCount + 1
    Else
    End If

End With
ShapeName = ""
TLeft = ""
TTop = ""
Application.CutCopyMode = False

End Function
Sub GeneratePresentation()

Dim FilePath, Filename, file As String
Dim MonthNo, MonthData As Variant
Dim x, y As Variant
Dim UpdateRecords As Integer
Dim WB As Excel.Workbook

FilePath = "\\\Model\"
Filename = "Template Weekly Report.pptx"
file = FilePath & Filename

Set pptApp = New PowerPoint.Application
Set pptPres = pptApp.Presentations.Open(file) ' using a specific presentation or template
Set pptPres = pptApp.ActivePresentation

TableCount = 1

'Slide 1 title 1
SlideNo = 1
Sheets("01").Range("D3") = "= ""Weekly Report """
Sheets("01").Range("D4") = "= ""For Week No. ""&TEXT(WEEKNUM(NOW(),16),""#"")& "" - internal"""
Set MyRange = Sheets("0" & SlideNo).Range("D3:D4")
TTop = 160
TLeft = 135
Call CreateTable

'Slide 1 title 2
Sheets("01").Range("D7").Formula = "=DAY(Entry!B4)&LOOKUP(DAY(Entry!B4),{1,2,3,4,21,22,23,24,31;""st"",""nd"",""rd"",""th"",""st"",""nd"",""rd"",""th"",""st""})&TEXT(Entry!B4,"" mmmm yyy"")"
Set MyRange = Sheets("0" & SlideNo).Range("D7")
TTop = 280
TLeft = 135
Call CreateTable

'slide 2 table 1
SlideNo = 2
Set MyRange = Sheets("0" & SlideNo).Range("B33:T40")
TTop = 380
Call CreateTable

'Slide 2 chart 1
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("0" & SlideNo).ChartObjects("Chart 1").Copy
Set osh = pSlide.Shapes.PasteSpecial(ppPasteMetafilePicture)(1)
With osh
    .Top = 98
    .Left = 35
    .Width = 430
End With

'Slide 3 table 1
SlideNo = 3
Set pSlide = pptPres.Slides(SlideNo)
UpdateRecords = MsgBox("Update Records", vbYesNo, "Update Records?")
If UpdateRecord = yes Then
    Set MyRange = Sheets("0" & SlideNo).Range("E17:I20")
    TTop = 330
    Call CreateTable
Else
End If

pptPres.Windows(1).Activate
pptPres.Windows(1).View.GotoSlide 1

End Sub
```

I hope this is helpful.

If you have any recommendation let me know.

Jon